# Laravel crear una foreign key en una migration

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Tengo una instalación limpia de laravel 5.8 con **passport**

Por una parte tengo la creación de la tabla de `users` con este código

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');

        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Y luego  otra  **migration** que quiero hacer referencia al campo **id** de la tabla **users** creada anteriormente.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users_profile', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsignedInteger();
        $table->boolean('supplements')->default(false);
        $table->float('imc')->nullable();
        $table->float('kcal')->nullable();

        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');

    });
}
```

Pues el error que recibo al ejecutar el comando migrations es el siguiente

Migrating: 2015_10_12_000000_create_users_profile_table

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `portal`.`#sql-3144_4` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") **(SQL: alter table `users_pro
>   file` add constraint `users_profile_user_id_foreign` foreign key (`user_id`) references `users` (`id`))**

Comment: Gracias , pero me da este error ----->    Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `portal`.`#sql-28b0_5` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `users_pro
file` add constraint `users_profile_user_id_foreign` foreign key (`user_id`) references `users` (`id`))

Comment: Te has fijado en el orden que tienes las migraciones. Trata que la migacion **Users** se cree primero que la migracion **Users_Profiles**

Comment: Si eso ya esta bien configurado , primero crea la tabla users y luego intenta crear la tabla users_profiles

Comment: Intenta cambiando `$table->integer('user_id')->unsignedInteger();` por esto `$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();`